# Hover not consistently working on animated element

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm rotating a div around a circular path with css, and I want to make it change color on hover.

See demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/gg7tnueu/1/

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.planet {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #1a1a1a;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  /*top: 50%;*/
  -webkit-animation: orbit 6s infinite linear;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  animation: orbit 6s infinite linear;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.planet.code {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 8.5vh 7.875vh;
  transform-origin: 8.5vh 7.875vh;
}

.planet.code:hover {
  background: red;
}

@-webkit-keyframes orbit {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes orbit {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.ring {
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #1a1a1a;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.ring.inner.middle {
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
}

.ring.inner.last {
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
}


@media (orientation: landscape) {
  .ring.outer {
    width: 75vh;
    height: 75vh;
  }
  .planet {
    width: 3.75vh;
    height: 3.75vh;
  }

}
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
  .ring.outer {
    width: 75vw;
    height: 75vw;
  }
  .planet {
    width: 3.75vw;
    height: 3.75vw;
    left: -1.875vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ring outer">
  <div class="ring inner middle">
    <div class="ring inner last">
      <div class='planet code'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The hover is detected pretty consistently in Firefox (when I add the -moz prefix...), but it's rarely detected in Chrome.

The same thing happens when I add an `onclick` handler.

Does anyone have any advice to make it work better?

**Screenshot of issue**

[image]

Comment: It also doesn't work in Safari.

Comment: It working fine for me. which Chrome are you using?

Comment: Chrome 41. Interestingly, it seems to work well on jsfiddle, but if I stick the code in a html file, it won't work.

Comment: Looks like some kind of Chrome optimization. The hover state is not recalculated if you don't move the cursor. Try setting the mouse on the path, ahead of the element, and keep it static. The hover won't trigger. It's also happening on Canary.

Comment: Yeah, if I put the mouse ahead of the element, even in the JSFiddle, the hover won't trigger. It does trigger consistently on the Fiddle so long as I move the mouse though. 

As opposed to in a local HTML file, where you have to hover over the place that it previously was, in order to get it to register at all, even if you're moving the mouse.

I'm going to try and see why it works better on the Fiddle, and see if I can emulate it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you'll have to use javascript since, as @vals said, the `:hover` state is not recalculated unless the mouse is moved.